# Does PhpStorm have a way to highlight hardcoded strings?

Tags: php, html, string, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have a config file where I store all my strings for easy reference and to make translation easier - just in case I ever need to roll out my application into one of our international locations.

I would like to remove my hardcoded strings from both HTML and PHP code.

[This site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/recognizing-hard-coded-string-literals.html) shows that IntelliJ IDEA is capable of highlighting hardcoded strings. However, I see no such option in my PhpStorm 2017.2 installation.

[image: PhpStorm Settings]

This is one example in HTML that I'd like to purge and replace with non-hardcoded strings:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="text-center">#</th>
    <th>Benutzername</th>
    <th>Nachname</th>
    <th>Vorname</th>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
    <th>Rollen</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

However, PhpStorm does not highlight the hardcoded strings or suggests any fix. Same goes for PHP code.

[image: error highlighting]

If it's of any interest, here's how I usually retrieve strings from my config array.

```
/**
 * Extract a string from the config file depending on its tag.
 *
 * @param string $tag The string to extract.
 *
 * @return mixed The string that was extracted. At least it should usually be a string, but it could also be
 *               something different, depending on the config.
 */
function get_string($tag)
{
    // Check the config file first.
    global $config;
    $string = $config['strings'][$tag];
    if (!isset($string)) {
        // The faulty tag can be found in the logfile.
        logfile("String Tag not found: " . $tag);
        $string = $tag;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

I simply give the array index to the function and retrieve the string from the config array. If I ever need internationalisation, I can modify this function.

Comment: HTML is text, it is normal to be made of elements and text pieces. The idea of "hardcoded string" in HTML is out of place, imho. Also PHP handles a lot of strings that are not "hardcoded strings". The array keys (including the values received from the front-end in `$_GET[]`, `$_POST[]` etc) are strings, file names (`include/require` etc) are strings. It's not an easy job even to define which are "hardcoded strings" and which are legitimate strings in a PHP script.

Comment: Hm, I hadn't thought about that. You're definitely right.

Comment: You can use the "Find in Files" command to find the strings in the PHP scripts (search for `['"]` and check "RegExp") but you'll probably be overwhelmed by the big number of strings, many of them being array keys or other strings (separators, SQL queries) that are part of the code, not of the output.

Comment: That would solve the question, but would certainly not help. I guess I'll just search for them manually. What do you think I should do with the question, leave it open or answer it myself?

Comment: If you have reached a conclusion then go ahead and provide an answer. Writing it helps you make a better plan for how to proceed and will probably help others that have the same issue.

Comment: Im also curious to know as a fellow PHPStorm user why this function is not available to me Edit : Apparently this an a Intellij IDEA only feature w/ Java ?

Comment: @morganwebdev: It would be quite tedious to tag every single array identifier as an "okay" string. While developing in PHP, you will always hardcode some strings and parameterize others. There is no avoiding it, you just have to pay attention to make those strings which are shown to users translatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'cmd + f' and search for >[a-z0-9] which does a decent job finding any instances where an HTML tag ends and a string begins

Answer (score 0):

@axiac provided a different point of view.

HTML is in itself basically full of hardcoded strings - tags et cetera.

PHP requires many strings to work. `$_GET[]`, `$_POST[]` and array indices like my `$config['strings'][$tag]` are a few examples.

If PhpStorm were to highlight all of these strings, all of them would have to be excluded from inspection manually.

As @axiac said:

> You can use the "Find in Files" command to find the strings in the PHP
>   scripts (search for `['"]` and check "RegExp") but you'll probably be
>   overwhelmed by the big number of strings, many of them being array
>   keys or other strings (separators, SQL queries) that are part of the
>   code, not of the output.